# SQL JSON - How to modify boolean value present in the Json Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, database

How can I modify the existing boolean value of a json data in SQL Server 2016 - Json?

Below is the script for inserting json Data.

```
DECLARE @a nvarchar(max) = N'{"employeeName":"Test","isActive":true}';

insert into TestTable(testId,name,jsonData) Values('1','Test',@a)
```

I tried to update using below query, but it returns 
*Invalid column name 'false'.*

```
update TestTable
set jsonData = JSON_MODIFY(jsonData,'$.isActive',false)
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `CAST(0 as BIT)`

```
update TestTable
set jsonData = JSON_MODIFY(jsonData, '$.isActive', CAST(0 as BIT))
```

If you want to set it to true, it is simply `CAST(1 as BIT)` instead.

This works because in SQL, a boolean is represented as a BIT, which can only be 0 or 1. In its translation to JSON, it converts a bit of 0 to false, and a bit of 1 to true.